# How to write twitter tweets to file using Spark Streaming Java API

Tags: twitter, apache-spark, streaming

I have the following code segment and I am trying to collect some tweets from the timeline of say "stefanjdecker". The actual credentials of mine have been changed to make myself anonymous.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(600));
String consumerKey = "key";
String accessTokenSecret = "secret";
String consumerSecret = "consumer";
String accessToken = "token";

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey);     
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret);       
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken); 
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret);
String[] filters = new String[] {"stefanjdecker"};
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc,filters);
twitterStream.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("/Output/twitter","txt");
```

The above code runs successfully. However, tweets are not being written to the path I mentioned. Please someone help me to sort this out.

Comment: Try local[*] or local[n] where n >= 2 in setMaster method.

Comment: Also try `twitterStream.foreachRDD {inside arg0.foreach{ Files.write(Paths.get("/Output/twitter.txt"), arg0._2().getBytes())}}`

Comment: I have changed the line JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc,filters); to JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc, NA, filters); and now it's working, where Authorization NA = null;